# Spring Cloud Config Client - Aggregate Config with the same prefix

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

I have following config loaded via Spring Cloud Config Server in a Spring Boot Microservice application:

```
{
  "routes": {
    "list": [
      {
        "a": "a1",
        "b": "b1"
      },
      {
        "a": "a2",
        "b": "b2"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

And in my client Spring Boot application I have following which maps the config to the Object:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties( prefix = "routes" )
public class MyClass
{
    private List<MyDest> list = new ArrayList<>();
.
.
```

Now I am trying to load more configs (files) with the exactly same structure mentioned above however I would like to aggregate them in the same Class listed above under the 'list' object.

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to section 2.8.7 from following link

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config

It clearly states (though for loading properties across different profiles)-
When lists are configured in more than one place, overriding works by replacing the entire list.

I believe same is the case for properties defined across multiple files though held under same profile.

This particular use case is not supported by Spring boot please refer to following threads around this for more details

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6670

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/9137

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/16394